# Passing generic type of webmethod

Tags: c#, silverlight, c#-3.0, web-services, asmx

im passing a array of `KeyValuePair<string,string>[]`

how ever when it get to my sliverlight client it turns into

`{web service name}.KeyValuePairOfStringString`

and i cant get the values from it.

any one got any ideas how i can access the key and value propties?

Comment: How are you generating your client proxy?  KeyValuePairOfStringString is likely the type in the WSDL, because you can't have generics in WSDL.  You probably want to create explicit DataContracts for each form of KeyValuePair you intend to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not be using ASMX web services with SilverLight. You should use WCF instead.